# RabbitMQ Hold the queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, node-amqp

I want to hold the rabbitMQ queue and then combine the previous transactions of the queue which were paused. Suppose I have a limit that after only 5 transactions I will proceed. I want to combine these 5 transactions and acknowledge the channel that the 5 transactions got completed.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "transactions of the queue"? There is no concept of transaction in AMQP.

Comment: I mean messages @LutzHorn

Comment: So you want to have a consumer that receives messages from a queue. Five of these messages belong together and only after the fifth message has been received by the consumer you want to ACK all five messages. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, and I want all those msgs as well to send to another server for notification purpose so I want to send an ack and want all those messages as well. @LutzHorn

Comment: And I want to do it via SDK so please don't suggest any rabbitmqctl commands.